# yahoo pipes not integrating all the feed

Tags: yahoo-pipes

i created this yahoo http://pipes.yahoo.com/lifestream_ashu/7ba696f34ae17b6fa8f5d4de13064de'>pipe to integrate my twitter+last.fm+picasa feed ..now when i am redering it as json all i can see is the last.fm feed.why is it so ?

link

> http://pipes.yahoo.com/lifestream_ashu/7ba696f34ae17b6fa8f5d4de13064dea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like now they are .. probably it was a temporary gitch on the server.